# Count with IF condition in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join, if-statement, count

I have two tables, one is for news and the other one is for comments and I want to get the count of the comments whose status has been set as approved.

```
SELECT
    ccc_news . *, 
    count(if(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved', ccc_news_comments.id, 0)) AS comments
FROM
    ccc_news
    LEFT JOIN
        ccc_news_comments
    ON ccc_news_comments.news_id = ccc_news.news_id
WHERE
    `ccc_news`.`category` = 'news_layer2'
    AND `ccc_news`.`status` = 'Active'
GROUP BY
    ccc_news.news_id
ORDER BY
    ccc_news.set_order ASC
LIMIT 20
```

But the problem with this query is that the minimum value that is fetched for the comments column is 1 whether there is any comment existent corresponding to that news or not.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: What if you use SUM instead of COUNT ?

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Use `sum()` in place of `count()`

Try below:

```
SELECT
    ccc_news . * , 
    SUM(if(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved', 1, 0)) AS comments
FROM
    ccc_news
    LEFT JOIN
        ccc_news_comments
    ON
        ccc_news_comments.news_id = ccc_news.news_id
WHERE
    `ccc_news`.`category` = 'news_layer2'
    AND `ccc_news`.`status` = 'Active'
GROUP BY
    ccc_news.news_id
ORDER BY
    ccc_news.set_order ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Or even SUM(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved') as a MySQL-specific trick

Comment: @mojuba not 100% the same, your trick returns `null` when `COUNT` (no conditions) would've returned `0`. When `COUNT` would've returned anything *but* 0, but the `SUM` *does* return 0, your trick returns `0`.

Comment: @mojuba [case and point](http://pastebin.com/JRqATRHB). `num_relevant_parts` is `SUM` with conditions, `num_total_parts` is `COUNT(parts.id)` (sorry for double comment, was too late to edit)

Answer (score 98):

Better still (or shorter anyway):

```
SUM(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved')
```

This works since the Boolean type in MySQL is represented as `INT` `0` and `1`, just like in C. (May not be portable across DB systems though.)

As for `COALESCE()` as mentioned in other answers, many language APIs automatically convert `NULL` to `''` when fetching the value. For example with PHP's `mysqli` interface it would be safe to run your query without `COALESCE()`.

Comment: This makes for significantly more readable sql code. Beautiful solution.

Comment: Always finding this answer when searching for the problem, works as a charm with likely no downsides

Answer (score 40):

This should work:

```
count(if(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved', ccc_news_comments.id, NULL))
```

`count()` only check if the value exists or not. 0 is equivalent to an existent value, so it counts one more, while NULL is like a non-existent value, so is not counted.

Comment: I think `count` is more intuitive than `sum` in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Replace this line:

```
count(if(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved', ccc_news_comments.id, 0)) AS comments
```

With this one:

```
coalesce(sum(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved'), 0) comments
```

Comment: count(if(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved', ccc_news_comments.id, 0)) ??? what will be meaning of using sum if  you use ccc_news_comments.id

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? The boolean value becomes 0 or 1, then sum, and in case there is some null value coalesce with 0

Comment: @MostyMostacho, does `COALESCE` return the sum ? Any reference in MySQL doc ?

Comment: Yes, why would't it? There are many references in the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 5):

```
count(ccc_news_comments.id = 'approved' or null)
```

More concise

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30047999)