# COUNT MAX CASE and GROUP BY for recurring type id

Tags: mysql

I have this view, resulting from a multiple join:

```
project_id  | document_type_id
10          | 2
10          | 2
10          | 3
10          | 1
10          | 1
10          | 1
11          | 2
11          | 2
11          | 2
11          | 2
11          | 3
11          | 3
```

label for 1: "review"

label for 2: "interview"

label for 3: "romance"

I already obtained this table:

```
project_id  | review     | interview | romance
10          | OK         | OK        | OK
11          | NO         | OK        | OK
```

using the following query statement:

```
SELECT `project_id`, `document_type_id`,
MAX(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 1 THEN "OK" ELSE "NO" END) as "review",
MAX(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 2 THEN "OK" ELSE "NO" END) as "interview",
MAX(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 3 THEN "OK" ELSE "NO" END) as "romance"

FROM projectDocumentList
GROUP BY project_id
```

What I need now is to count every document type in each field in a table like that:

```
project_id  | review | interview | romance
10          | 3      | 2         | 1
11          | 0      | 4         | 2
```

I tried and tried but I cannot find the correct sintax to obtain this result.
Some of my previous attempts...

```
COUNT(MAX(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 1 THEN "1" ELSE "NO" END)) as "review"

MAX(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 1 THEN (SELECT COUNT(`document_type_id`)) ELSE "NO" END) as "review"

COUNT(DISTINCT(MAX(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 1 THEN `document_type_id` ELSE "NO" END)) as "review"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count with if condition in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798937/count-with-if-condition-in-mysql-query)

Comment: What's your primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM()`

**Query**

```
SELECT `project_id`,
SUM(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "review",
SUM(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "interview",
SUM(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "romance"
FROM projectDocumentList
GROUP BY project_id
```

**Results**

```
| project_id | review | interview | romance |
| ---------- | ------ | --------- | ------- |
| 10         | 3      | 2         | 1       |
| 11         | 0      | 4         | 2       |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFDBr6hpZCtVdBEqRqgpqB/1)

Or `COUNT(..)` can also be used but you need to use `NULL` instead of `0`. 
This is because `COUNT(..)` handles [0, 1 and NULL values](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uPtFrKLscdmYntyrpcYKUQ/2) different then `SUM(..)` does.

**Query**

```
SELECT `project_id`,
COUNT(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "review",
COUNT(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "interview",
COUNT(CASE WHEN `document_type_id` = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "romance"
FROM projectDocumentList
GROUP BY project_id
```

**Results**

```
| project_id | review | interview | romance |
| ---------- | ------ | --------- | ------- |
| 10         | 3      | 2         | 1       |
| 11         | 0      | 4         | 2       |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFDBr6hpZCtVdBEqRqgpqB/3)